# bootstrap selectpicker after refresh the dropdown, option selection not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, dropdown

- am using Boostrap selectpicker dropdwon from this Link [Lib-DropDown](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
- am facing the issue is after refresh the dropdown list by using **'refresh'** method then selecting option not working properly [i.e. selecting one option its selected another option]
- my fiddle is **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rajinikanth06/c79prh7j/5/)**
- if am selecting Active its selected as InActive.
- if am not using $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh') then it is working fine but disable not working.
- please help on this and save my days, thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});

function enableForAdd() {
  enable();
}

function enable() {
  $('#Status').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#Status').selectpicker('refresh');
  //$('#Status').selectpicker();
  //$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="Status" id="lblStatus">Status</label>
  <select class="selectpicker" disabled id="Status" name="Status" >
    <option value="Active">Active</option>
    <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
  </select>
  <div><a id="addButton" onclick="enableForAdd()" title="Add ">CLICK-ADD</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Check out my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/c79prh7j/16/. Bootstrap Select plugin requires Bootstrap’s dropdown.js component and Bootstrap's CSS. Have you included them in your project?

Comment: @andreivictor, thanks for repaly, am using these libs. please checkout this once **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0clpJqaCPujM6f44lF2?p=preview)**.

Comment: You need to include jQuery before any other script. The final order of scripts should be: jQuery, Bootstrap JS, then Bootstrap Select, then your custom script file.

Comment: @andreivictor, ok thank you, i have added exact which files am using in my project, please can you check if you are free, **[MyUploadedFiles](http://plnkr.co/edit/nggqaUaWMgKtUdw8YA2U)** .am unable to find issue.in project selectpicker working but when selecting 1st option(Active) its selected as 2nd option(InActive), this happends only for disabled dropdown after Enabled..

Comment: Hey, check out this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/v69BXwcijdXsvmZPhCHy?p=preview. I think is working okay...